# How to align equation with text?

Tags: align

Can anyone help me solve this? I have tried everything to write this but it is still not working.

[image]

I tried:

```
\begin{equation}\label{BM2}
\begin{align*}
   \dot{c} &= -Div \textbf{h} + h  && \text{em $\mathcal{P}$}\\
   \textbf{h.n}&=h && \text{em $\partial \mathcal{P}$}
\end{align*}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Why do you nest an `align*` into an `equation`? (I'm surprised this even compiles for you.) If you remove the `equation`, it aligns correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't nest an `align` environment into an `equation` environment. `align` is a math environment itself, so it doesn't need to be called inside of an `equation` environment. In fact, doing this causes errors.

The following aligns correctly:

```
\begin{align*}
   \dot{c} &= -Div \textbf{h} + h  && \text{em $\mathcal{P}$}\\
   \textbf{h.n}&=h && \text{em $\partial \mathcal{P}$}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: This won't produce a number.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but Egreg managed to put the equation number there. This solved my problem! Thank you

Comment: @egreg Right, I didn't know there was supposed to be a number.
Happy it was solved!

Answer (score 1):

You get

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.
```

The error message says all: you should use `aligned`.

However there are other points to fix: the “divergence” operator should be typeset upright and the period should most probably be centered. You also want `\mathbf` rather than `\textbf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div} % <--- important!

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{BM2}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{c} &= -\Div\mathbf{h} + h  && \text{em $\mathcal{P}$}\\
\mathbf{h}\cdot\mathbf{n} &= h  && \text{em $\partial \mathcal{P}$}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, with left alignment as in the original picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div} % <--- important!

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{BM2}
\begin{aligned}
&\dot{c} = -\Div\mathbf{h} + h  && \text{em $\mathcal{P}$}\\
&\mathbf{h}\cdot\mathbf{n} = h  && \text{em $\partial \mathcal{P}$}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thank you a lot for your reply. I was really searching for all these tips (not only my question LOL!) and you just solved them. Thank you!