# Relatively new to Latex, wondering what the easiest way to format a problem such as this?

Tags: formatting, logicproof

[image]

I have been using hspace to space things out, but it's really tedious to get it lined up correctly and there's no way that is the best way lol

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot ...

Comment: Could this https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391424/how-to-align-equation-with-text help

Comment: @Mensch Unfortunately, it is from a PDF, and was wondering what I could write in LaTex to produce the same type of proof format

Comment: But "I have been using hspace to space things out" suggests that you have something.  That would have given us something to start from as well as showing how much of TeX you do already understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways. First using `tabular` (no packages needed). Second using `aligned` (requires `amsmath`), and third using `align*` (also uses `amsmath`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$x\in(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\setminus (A\cap B)$
\[
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\equiv(x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)$ & \textsf{Def of Difference}\\
$\equiv((x\in\overline{A})\vee x\in\overline{B})\land(\lnot(x\in A\cup B)$ & \textsf{Def of Union}\\
$\equiv(\cdots$ & \textsf{Def of \dots}
\end{tabular}
\]

\vspace{1cm}
$x\in(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\setminus (A\cap B)$
\[
\begin{aligned}
&\equiv(x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B) && \textsf{Def of Difference}\\
&\equiv((x\in\overline{A})\vee x\in\overline{B})\land(\lnot(x\in A\cup B) && \textsf{Def of Union}\\
&\equiv(\cdots && \textsf{Def of \dots}
\end{aligned}
\]

\vspace{1cm}
$x\in(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\setminus (A\cap B)$
\begin{align*}
&\equiv(x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B) && \textsf{Def of Difference}\\
&\equiv((x\in\overline{A})\vee x\in\overline{B})\land(\lnot(x\in A\cup B) && \textsf{Def of Union}\\
&\equiv(\cdots && \textsf{Def of \dots}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `align*`?

Comment: Excellent, thank you for taking the time do that, I really appreciate it

Comment: @IanThompson: Yes, of course it would. I must not be thinking clearly.  I'll add the option to my response.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be sure that TeX will keep the whole thing together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\justif}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\cmpl}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\MoveEqLeft x\in (\cmpl{A}\cup\cmpl{B})\setminus(A\cap B) \\[1ex]
&\equiv (x\in\cmpl{A}\cup\cmpl{B})\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B) 
  && \justif{Def of Difference} \\
&\equiv ((x\in\cmpl{A})\lor(x\in\cmpl{B}))\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Def of Union} \\
&\equiv (\lnot(x\in A)\lor\lnot(x\in B))\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Def of Complement} \\
&\equiv \lnot((x\in A)\land(x\in B))\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{De Morgan} \\
&\equiv \lnot(x\in A\cap B)\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Def of Intersection} \\
&\equiv \lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Idempotence} \\
&\equiv x\in\cmpl{A\cap B}
  && \justif{Def of Complement}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace with

```
\begin{flalign*}
\quad
\MoveEqLeft x\in (\cmpl{A}\cup\cmpl{B})\setminus(A\cap B) \\[1ex]
<the same code as before follows>
\end{align*}
```

you get

[image]

Why the commands `\justif` and `\compl`? Suppose you or your coauthor finds the `\overline` to be ugly (I do, for instance). You may decide to experiment a different notation. Changing into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

% widebar, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391193/4427
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-> mathx10 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{\mathalpha}{mathx}{"73}

\newcommand{\justif}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
%\newcommand{\cmpl}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\cmpl}[1]{\widebar{#1}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\begin{flalign*}
\quad\MoveEqLeft x\in (\cmpl{A}\cup\cmpl{B})\setminus(A\cap B) \\[1ex]
&\equiv (x\in\cmpl{A}\cup\cmpl{B})\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B) 
  && \justif{Def of Difference} \\
&\equiv ((x\in\cmpl{A})\lor(x\in\cmpl{B}))\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Def of Union} \\
&\equiv (\lnot(x\in A)\lor\lnot(x\in B))\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Def of Complement} \\
&\equiv \lnot((x\in A)\land(x\in B))\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{De Morgan} \\
&\equiv \lnot(x\in A\cap B)\land\lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Def of Intersection} \\
&\equiv \lnot(x\in A\cap B)
  && \justif{Idempotence} \\
&\equiv x\in\cmpl{A\cap B}
  && \justif{Def of Complement}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

would turn the output (`flalign*` version) into

[image]

Similarly, if your coauthor doesn't like sans serif type, you can just change the definition of `\justif`.